# Change property of treeview selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I have a treeview template like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:Category}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CategoryName}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:Product}">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Add To Project" Click="MenuItem_OnClick"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ModelName}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And I am trying to add the treeview item to the linkedlist:

```
LinkedList<Product> dll = new LinkedList<Product>();
private void MenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var itemToAdd = this.tv_Project.SelectedItem as Product;
     Product previous = dll.ElementAt(dll.Count - 1);

     if(itemToAdd.CategoryID == 1)
     {
          dll.AddLast(ItemToAdd);
     }
     else if(itemToAdd.CategoryID == 2)
     {
          itemToAdd.ProductValue = previous.ProductValue + 1;
     }
     ...
}
```

Now when I run the above code, I found that if the `previous`(which I added to the linkedlist last time) and the `itemToAdd`(which I'm going to add to linkedlist this time) are the same, it changes the Property `ProductValue` of both `previous` and `itemToAdd` when this code execute:

```
itemToAdd.ProductValue = previous.ProductValue + 1;
```

So how should I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The LinkedList contains *references* to Product objects. So if two references refer to the same object, this object may be changed using any of these references.

Comment: @mm8 Thanks for your reply. I believe so. I alse tried `Array`, it has the same problem. So could you please tell me what should I do if I want to achieve that?

Comment: I don't understand what your code is supposed to do and what you are trying to accomplish. And using an Array instead of a LinkedList makes no difference at all. You are still storing references.

Comment: I want to change the invoke value but not the reference. The value in the linkedlist should be changed dynamic but not the `SelectedItem`. In this case: when I execute `itemToAdd.ProductValue = previous.ProductValue + 1;' the `previous.ProductValue` shouldn't be changed while the itemToAdd.ProductValue` shall be changed

Comment: The value in the list and the SelectedItem are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The `LinkedList<T>` contains *references* to `Product` objects. So if two references refer to the same object, this object may be changed using any of these references.

You may want to try to add *copies* of products to the `LinkedList<T>`:

```
/* create a new Product object here and set all of its properties: */
ddl.AddLast(new Product() { Name = ItemsToAdd.Name });
```

You may also want to read up on how reference types work in .NET.

And on the differences between reference and value types:

[What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c)

Depending on your requirements, you may want to define `Product` as a value type (`struct`).